# Introducing branches to my model

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm currently programming a supply chain in AnyLogic, which consists of 2 Manufacturers producing parts for a single Retailer. This Retailer sells his goods to two different customers. My simplified solution looks like this:

[image]

Given I need two branches for this (Distribution coming from Manufacturer A and B to Retailer and from Retailer to his two customers) I've used the logic attached. But It doesn't work out. How can I introduce this to my model?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You could parameterize your statechart, so that it is a generic manufacturer-to-retailer/retailer-to-customer flow, but with methods & variables being used to determine *which* manufacturer/retailer to use.
2. You can use a branch within the statechart.

[image]

3. You can look at the process library class and consider the more traditional flow chart blocks.  I find that the process blocks tend to be easier to conceptualize when you are wanted to have multiple decide steps in a flow chart type view.  Keep in mind, that you can still have an agent based paradigm with the process flow blocks.  That is, the product object could send itself through its own process flow blocks.